# Merge two df and replace values if condition is met Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to combine two df's with Pyspark with a condition. They both have same number and name of columns, and my key variable is 'id'.

Condition: For the columns of df1 whose value is Null() I want to leave it like this, otherwise replace them with the value of df2.

I found this approach, but I don't know how to do it for all columns. I have 51 columns in my df's.

```py
result = df1.join(df2, on=['id']).
            withColumn('_col1', when(df1['col1'].isNull(), df1['col1']).otherwise(df2['col1'])).
            withColumn('_col2', when(df1['col2'].isNull(), df1['col2']).otherwise(df2['col2'])).
            select('id', '_col1', '_col2', 'col3', 'col4').
            toDF('id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'))
```

This is an example of what I have:

df1

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | null | false | false | false |
| y | false | false | false | false |
| z | null | null | null | false |

df2

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 5 | 4 | 12 | 56 |
| y | 23 | 5 | 3 | 79 |
| z | 34 | 45 | 23 | 2 |

And this is the expected result:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | null | 4 | 12 | 56 |
| y | 23 | 5 | 3 | 79 |
| z | null | null | null | 2 |

I would appreciate any suggestion :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works indeed! The only thing that does not make sense is the input dataframe's data types (they should have the same). So I made this example using the following dataframes (`df1` has `1` values everywhere you used `false`):

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("x ", None, 1, 1, 1),
        ("y ", 1, 1, 1, 1),
        ("z ", None, None, None, 1)
    ],
    ["id", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col_n"]
)

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("x ", 5, 4, 12, 56),
        ("y ", 23, 5, 3, 79),
        ("z ", 34, 45, 23, 2)
    ],
    ["id", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col_n"]
)
```

So what you can do is extending your code to a `for` loop:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

joinedDf = df1.join(df2, on=['id'])

for c in df1.columns:
    if c != "id":
        joinedDf = joinedDf \
            .withColumn(f"temp-{c}", when(df1[c].isNull(), df1[c]).otherwise(df2[c])) \
            .drop(c) \
            .withColumnRenamed(f"temp-{c}", c)
```

As you can see in this snippet, we're simply renaming the final column to a temporary name, dropping the original columns and then renaming it to the original name again.

This results in:

```
>>> joinedDf.show()
+---+----+----+----+-----+
| id|col1|col2|col3|col_n|
+---+----+----+----+-----+
| x |null|   4|  12|   56|
| y |  23|   5|   3|   79|
| z |null|null|null|    2|
+---+----+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: It totally worked with the example! Thank you very much. The sad part is that it's not working with my df's. I keep getting the error 'AnalysisException': Column are ambiguous...' But i don't really get why because when I apply the code on the examples it does not flag any error

Comment: I also changed the dtypes of the columns so in theory it should not be causing any issue.

Comment: Good stuff! :) About your issue: could you check both `df1.dtypes` and `df2.dtypes` and verify whether they are the same? If not, you should try to fix that (for example by casting columns to the correct types). If they are the same, I suggest you make another SO question with that AnalysisException error in there (including the full stack trace).